# Slow performance MySql query, alternatives / suggestions?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, limit, group-concat

I'm implementing a search filter page in my coin website but it's quite slow now that I have many entries:
[image: Search Page]

Here is the query when no filter is selected:

```
SELECT
    i.id_items AS id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iant.translation ORDER BY iant.translation asc SEPARATOR ', ') AS names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iafv.face_value ORDER BY iafv.face_value ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS facesValues,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacut.translation ORDER BY iacut.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS currencies,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cout.translation ORDER BY cout.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS countries,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacot.translation ORDER BY iacot.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS compositions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacc.catalog_code ORDER BY iacc.catalog_code ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS catalogCodes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iaio.issues_on ORDER BY iaio.issues_on ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS issuesOn,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iali.last_issues ORDER BY iali.last_issues ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS latestIssues,
    MIN(ucfs.price) AS minPrice,
    SUM(ucfs.units) AS totalUnits    
FROM
    items i
INNER JOIN languages AS l 
    ON l.language_code = "en"

LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values_match AS iafvm 
    ON iafvm.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values AS iafv 
    ON iafv.id_items_atr_faces_values = iafvm.id_items_atr_faces_values


LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_match AS iacum 
    ON iacum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_translations AS iacut 
    ON iacut.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies
    AND iacut.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies AS iacu 
    ON iacu.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_match AS iacoum 
    ON iacoum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_translations AS cout 
    ON cout.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries
    AND cout.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries AS cou 
    ON cou.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_match AS iacom 
    ON iacom.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_translations AS iacot 
    ON iacot.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions 
    AND iacot.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions AS iaco 
    ON iaco.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes_match AS iaccm 
    ON iaccm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes AS iacc 
    ON iacc.id_items_atr_catalog_codes = iaccm.id_items_atr_catalog_codes


LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on_match AS iaiom 
    ON iaiom.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on AS iaio 
    ON iaio.id_items_atr_issues_on = iaiom.id_items_atr_issues_on

LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues_match AS ialim 
    ON ialim.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues AS iali 
    ON iali.id_items_atr_last_issues = ialim.id_items_atr_last_issues


LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_match AS ianm 
    ON ianm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_translations AS iant 
    ON iant.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names 
    AND iant.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names AS ian 
    ON ian.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names          


LEFT JOIN users AS u On u.status = 'active' 
LEFT JOIN users_coins_for_sale AS ucfs 
    ON ucfs.id_users = u.id_users AND ucfs.id_items = i.id_items  



GROUP BY id

ORDER BY 2 asc

LIMIT 0, 20
```

Here the explanation:

[image: Query Explanation]

I'm using Group Concat since each item can have one or more matches with the attributes (name, face value, etc).

The query takes 1.3 seconds to run with 15k entries. The tables will have up 100k entries eventually, so the time to run the query will be increased too...

At first I thought the Group_Concat was the responsable to slow down the query but then, after removing the LIMIT 0, 20 I saw it takes the same time to run.

I tried to put the Limit in a subquery:

```
...
FROM
    (SELECT id_items FROM items LIMIT 0, 20) AS i
INNER JOIN languages AS l 
...
```

Now the query is fast but the result is not what I expected.

Do you have guys any suggestion to fix this query?

Also, I am having a similar problem in this query, to count the number of items:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.id_items) AS number  
FROM
    items i
INNER JOIN languages AS l 
    ON l.language_code = "en"

LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values_match AS iafvm 
    ON iafvm.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values AS iafv 
    ON iafv.id_items_atr_faces_values = iafvm.id_items_atr_faces_values


LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_match AS iacum 
    ON iacum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_translations AS iacut 
    ON iacut.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies
    AND iacut.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies AS iacu 
    ON iacu.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_match AS iacoum 
    ON iacoum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_translations AS cout 
    ON cout.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries
    AND cout.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries AS cou 
    ON cou.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_match AS iacom 
    ON iacom.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_translations AS iacot 
    ON iacot.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions 
    AND iacot.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions AS iaco 
    ON iaco.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes_match AS iaccm 
    ON iaccm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes AS iacc 
    ON iacc.id_items_atr_catalog_codes = iaccm.id_items_atr_catalog_codes


LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on_match AS iaiom 
    ON iaiom.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on AS iaio 
    ON iaio.id_items_atr_issues_on = iaiom.id_items_atr_issues_on

LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues_match AS ialim 
    ON ialim.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues AS iali 
    ON iali.id_items_atr_last_issues = ialim.id_items_atr_last_issues


LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_match AS ianm 
    ON ianm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_translations AS iant 
    ON iant.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names 
    AND iant.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names AS ian 
    ON ian.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names          


LEFT JOIN users AS u On u.status = 'active' 
LEFT JOIN users_coins_for_sale AS ucfs 
    ON ucfs.id_users = u.id_users AND ucfs.id_items = i.id_items  

LIMIT 1
```

That takes 0.8 seconds.

Explanation:[image: Explanation]

I run the two queries in my search page (need the second one for the pagination), so it end up taking 2 seconds to load. Now with 15k items, so when I have 100K it will take much longer.

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Update: Here is the creation data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_users` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `views` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` enum('draft','published') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    KEY `id_users` (`id_users`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_users` FOREIGN KEY (`id_users`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_users`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Lista de items';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_catalog_codes` (
    `id_items_atr_catalog_codes` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `catalog_code` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_catalog_codes` (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `catalog_code` (`catalog_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Los diferentes códigos de catálogo que tienen las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_catalog_codes_match` (
    `id_items_atr_catalog_codes_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_catalog_codes` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_catalog_codes_match` (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes_match`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_catalog_codes` (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_codes_items_match_catalog_codes` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes`) REFERENCES `items_atr_catalog_codes` (`id_items_atr_catalog_codes`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_codes_items_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociación de monedas con los códigos del catálogo';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_compositions` (
    `id_items_atr_compositions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_compositions`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_compositions` (`id_items_atr_compositions`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Lista de las diferentes composiciones';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_compositions_match` (
    `id_items_atr_compositions_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_compositions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_compositions_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_compositions_match` (`id_items_atr_compositions_match`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_compositions` (`id_items_atr_compositions`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_compositions_items_match_compositions` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_compositions`) REFERENCES `items_atr_compositions` (`id_items_atr_compositions`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_compositions_items_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Las diferentes composiciones que puede tener un item';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_compositions_translations` (
    `id_items_atr_compositions_translations` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_compositions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_language_code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `translation` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_compositions_translations`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_compositions_translations` (`id_items_atr_compositions_translations`),
    KEY `id_language_code` (`id_language_code`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_compositions` (`id_items_atr_compositions`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `translation` (`translation`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_compositions_translations_compositions` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_compositions`) REFERENCES `items_atr_compositions` (`id_items_atr_compositions`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_compositions_translations_languages` FOREIGN KEY (`id_language_code`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id_languages`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Traducciones de las composiciones';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_countries` (
    `id_items_atr_countries` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_countries`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_countries` (`id_items_atr_countries`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_countries_match` (
    `id_items_atr_countries_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_countries` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_countries_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `items_atr_countries_match` (`id_items_atr_countries_match`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_countries` (`id_items_atr_countries`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__countries` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_countries`) REFERENCES `items_atr_countries` (`id_items_atr_countries`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='A que pais pertenece cada item';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_countries_translations` (
    `id_items_atr_countries_translations` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_countries` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_language_code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `translation` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_countries_translations`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_countries_translations` (`id_items_atr_countries_translations`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_countries` (`id_items_atr_countries`),
    KEY `id_language_code` (`id_language_code`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `translation` (`translation`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__items_atr_countries` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_countries`) REFERENCES `items_atr_countries` (`id_items_atr_countries`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_countries_translations_languages` FOREIGN KEY (`id_language_code`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id_languages`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_currencies` (
    `id_items_atr_currencies` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_currencies`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_currencies` (`id_items_atr_currencies`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Diferentes divisas de las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_currencies_match` (
    `id_items_atr_currencies_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_currencies` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_currencies_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_currencies_match` (`id_items_atr_currencies_match`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_currencies` (`id_items_atr_currencies`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_currencies_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_currencies_match_items_atr_currencies` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_currencies`) REFERENCES `items_atr_currencies` (`id_items_atr_currencies`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociación de las monedas con su divisa';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_currencies_translations` (
    `id_items_atr_currencies_translations` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_currencies` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_language_code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `translation` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_currencies_translations`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_currencies_translations` (`id_items_atr_currencies_translations`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_currencies` (`id_items_atr_currencies`),
    KEY `id_language_code` (`id_language_code`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `translation` (`translation`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_currencies_translations_items_atr_currencies` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_currencies`) REFERENCES `items_atr_currencies` (`id_items_atr_currencies`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_currencies_translations_languages` FOREIGN KEY (`id_language_code`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id_languages`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Traducciones de las divisas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_faces_values` (
    `id_items_atr_faces_values` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `face_value` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_faces_values`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_faces_values` (`id_items_atr_faces_values`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Valores faciales de las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_faces_values_match` (
    `id_items_atr_faces_values_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_faces_values` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_faces_values_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_faces_values_match` (`id_items_atr_faces_values_match`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_faces_values` (`id_items_atr_faces_values`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_faces_values_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_faces_values_match_items_atr_faces_values` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_faces_values`) REFERENCES `items_atr_faces_values` (`id_items_atr_faces_values`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociación de las monedas con sus valores faciales';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_issues_on` (
    `id_items_atr_issues_on` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `issues_on` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_issues_on`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_issues_on` (`id_items_atr_issues_on`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `issues_on` (`issues_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Fecha en la que se emitió por primera vez la moneda';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_issues_on_match` (
    `id_items_atr_issues_on_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_issues_on` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_issues_on_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_issues_on_match` (`id_items_atr_issues_on_match`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_issues_on` (`id_items_atr_issues_on`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_issues_on_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_issues_on_match_items_atr_issues_on` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_issues_on`) REFERENCES `items_atr_issues_on` (`id_items_atr_issues_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociaciones de emisiones con las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_last_issues` (
    `id_items_atr_last_issues` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `last_issues` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_last_issues`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_last_issues` (`id_items_atr_last_issues`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `last_issues` (`last_issues`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Atributo de última emisión de la moneda';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_last_issues_match` (
    `id_items_atr_last_issues_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_last_issues` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_last_issues_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_last_issues_match` (`id_items_atr_last_issues_match`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_last_issues` (`id_items_atr_last_issues`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_last_issues_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_last_issues_match_items_atr_last_issues` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_last_issues`) REFERENCES `items_atr_last_issues` (`id_items_atr_last_issues`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociaciones entre las últimas emisiones y las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_names` (
    `id_items_atr_names` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_names`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_names` (`id_items_atr_names`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Contiene el atributo nombre de los items';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_names_match` (
    `id_items_atr_names_match` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_names` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_names_match`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_names_match` (`id_items_atr_names_match`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_names` (`id_items_atr_names`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_names_match_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_names_match_items_atr_names` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_names`) REFERENCES `items_atr_names` (`id_items_atr_names`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Asociación del atributo nombre con las monedas';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_atr_names_translations` (
    `id_items_atr_names_translations` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items_atr_names` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `id_language_code` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `translation` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_items_atr_names_translations`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_items_atr_names_translations` (`id_items_atr_names_translations`),
    KEY `id_language_code` (`id_language_code`),
    KEY `id_items_atr_names` (`id_items_atr_names`),
    KEY `STR_LEVE_idx` (`translation`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `translation` (`translation`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_names_translations_items_atr_names` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items_atr_names`) REFERENCES `items_atr_names` (`id_items_atr_names`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_items_atr_names_translations_languages` FOREIGN KEY (`id_language_code`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id_languages`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Traducciones del atributo nombre';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id_users` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_languages` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `password` char(128) NOT NULL,
    `user_name` char(128) NOT NULL,
    `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `ip_register` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ip_last_login` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fb_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fb_access_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `regen_password` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `activation_token` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
    `affiliated` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
    `credit` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `status` enum('inactive','active','vacation','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'inactive',
    `news` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `promotions` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_users`),
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
    KEY `id_languages` (`id_languages`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `fb_user_id` (`fb_user_id`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `email2` (`email`),
    FULLTEXT KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_languages` FOREIGN KEY (`id_languages`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id_languages`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Lista de usuarios en la web';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_coins_for_sale` (
    `id_users_coins_for_sale` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_items` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `id_users` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `units` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `year` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `grade` enum('good','very_good','fine','very_fine','extra_fine','about_uncirculated','uncirculated','brilliant_uncirculated','proof') NOT NULL,
    `price` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `picture` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_users_coins_for_sale`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_users_coins_for_sale_unique` (`id_users_coins_for_sale`),
    KEY `id_items` (`id_items`),
    KEY `id_users` (`id_users`),
    KEY `year` (`year`),
    KEY `grade` (`grade`),
    KEY `id_users_coins_for_sale` (`id_users_coins_for_sale`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_coins_for_sale_items` FOREIGN KEY (`id_items`) REFERENCES `items` (`id_items`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_users_coins_for_sale_users` FOREIGN KEY (`id_users`) REFERENCES `users` (`id_users`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Have you heard of using indices to speed up joins?  Besides that, your schema looks fairly large.  How many records are you dealing with here?

Comment: The second problem's more interesting. Note that questions about performance ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Strawberry I updated the answer with the data creation to see the data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very complicated query, because of all the Cartesian products being performed.  It is a bit hard to follow, because you provide no data model.

The key to improving performance is to do the aggregations *before* joining, so you don't get the Cartesian products.  There are two ways to do this.  One is to pre-aggregate tables in the `FROM` clause.  The other is to use correlated subqueries.  When you are further filtering the rows (say to get 20 rows), correlated subqueries are usually the better choice.

You can simplify it by using subqueries to do the aggregations *before* the joins.  To take one example of the aggregation:

```
SELECT i.id_items AS id,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(iafv.face_value SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM tems_atr_faces_values_match iafvm JOIN
             items_atr_faces_values iafv 
             ON  iafv.id_items_atr_faces_values = iafvm.id_items_atr_faces_values AND
                 iafvm.id_items = i.id_items 
       ) as facesValues
       . . .
FROM items i INNER JOIN
     languages AS l 
     ON l.language_code = 'en';
```

For this query, you then want indexes on `items_atr_faces_values_match(id_items, id_items_atr_faces_values)` and `items_atr_faces_values(id_items_atr_faces_values, face_value`.

You need to repeat this for all your relationships.

Comment: I updated the answer with the data creation to see the data model with the index I have. Gonna try to do your suggestion now

Comment: I just tried the way you suggested [link](https://pastebin.com/4Pu6se8f) but it takes the same amount of time to run, maybe 100 ms less

Comment: @NicolásGonzález . . . The subqueries should all be inner joins and the indexes are important.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff, seeing the link in my previous comment I see the index aren't exported but they are there, idk why heidi did't export them. The only case the sub query is left is when it's order by that table but there aren't restrict values . I'm gonna validate your answer since the sub queries helped me to fix the problems. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

Too many tables.

Do not "normalize" simple things such as face_value and issues_on (and probably others.  It leads to extra `JOINs` without extra flexibility, etc.

I see a country id, but no country name??  It may be better to use this *instead* of the table and id:

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

and use the standard 2-letter country codes.  (It will also replace a 4-byte `INT` with a 2-byte string in various tables.

Also, since a `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition (in MySQL), `UNIQUE`:

```
PRIMARY KEY(x)
UNIQUE     (x)  -- DROP this
```

Do you need `LEFT`?  That is, is the row in the 'right' table possibly missing?  If not, remove `LEFT`.

After you have cleaned up those, ask for another review.

Comment: Hi @rick-james, thanks for the suggestions. I use country_codes in the country table for my users but I can't use country codes in the items_atr_country table since the items use "non-existing" countries, such "Roman Empire". I need left joins becase some items don't have certain attributes (country, face value, etc could be missing) and I need a null reference to know there isn't match with the attribute. Thanks for the unique tip, I'll get rid of them. I appreciate your review, I'm not a db expert, I learn as I go.

Comment: A potentially missing attribute could be, for example `face_value` decimal(8,2) unsigned NULL DEFAULT NULL, thereby avoiding a JOIN.  (Unless there is more info there that you have not shown in the `CREATE TABLE`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, getting the results in 0.125 / 0.180 seconds

The trick is to perform a subquery first with the attribute you want to order by, and the selected pagination, then use the item id in the rest of joins.

Example, selecting name as the attribute to order by:

```
SELECT
    i.id_items AS id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iant.translation ORDER BY iant.translation asc SEPARATOR ', ') AS names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iafv.face_value ORDER BY iafv.face_value ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS facesValues,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacut.translation ORDER BY iacut.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS currencies,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cout.translation ORDER BY cout.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS countries,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacot.translation ORDER BY iacot.translation ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS compositions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iacc.catalog_code ORDER BY iacc.catalog_code ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS catalogCodes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iaio.issues_on ORDER BY iaio.issues_on ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS issuesOn,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iali.last_issues ORDER BY iali.last_issues ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS latestIssues,
    MIN(ucfs.price) AS minPrice,
    SUM(ucfs.units) AS totalUnits
FROM
    (SELECT
        i.id_items,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iant.translation ORDER BY iant.translation asc SEPARATOR ', ') AS names
    FROM
        items i
    INNER JOIN languages AS l ON l.language_code = "en"

    LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_match AS ianm ON ianm.id_items = i.id_items
    LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_translations AS iant ON iant.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names 
        AND iant.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
    LEFT JOIN items_atr_names AS ian ON ian.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names          

    GROUP BY id_items

    ORDER BY 2 asc

    LIMIT 0, 20) AS i
INNER JOIN languages AS l ON l.language_code = "en"

LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values_match AS iafvm ON iafvm.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_faces_values AS iafv ON iafv.id_items_atr_faces_values = iafvm.id_items_atr_faces_values

LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_match AS iacum ON iacum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies_translations AS iacut ON iacut.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies AND iacut.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies AS iacu ON iacu.id_items_atr_currencies = iacum.id_items_atr_currencies 


LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_match AS iacoum ON iacoum.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries_translations AS cout ON cout.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries AND cout.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_countries AS cou ON cou.id_items_atr_countries = iacoum.id_items_atr_countries 



LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_match AS iacom ON iacom.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions_translations AS iacot ON iacot.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions AND iacot.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_compositions AS iaco ON iaco.id_items_atr_compositions = iacom.id_items_atr_compositions 



LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes_match AS iaccm ON iaccm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_catalog_codes AS iacc ON iacc.id_items_atr_catalog_codes = iaccm.id_items_atr_catalog_codes


LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on_match AS iaiom ON iaiom.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_issues_on AS iaio ON iaio.id_items_atr_issues_on = iaiom.id_items_atr_issues_on


LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues_match AS ialim ON ialim.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_last_issues AS iali ON iali.id_items_atr_last_issues = ialim.id_items_atr_last_issues


LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_match AS ianm ON ianm.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names_translations AS iant ON iant.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names AND iant.id_language_code = l.id_languages 
LEFT JOIN items_atr_names AS ian ON ian.id_items_atr_names = ianm.id_items_atr_names          

LEFT JOIN users AS u On u.status = 'active' 
LEFT JOIN users_coins_for_sale AS ucfs ON ucfs.id_users = u.id_users AND ucfs.id_items = i.id_items  


GROUP BY id

ORDER BY 2 asc
```

I hope this answer saves time to someone else.

Peace